# [WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.]

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

I am working in two environments, staging and production.  In stage, my site pulls up correctly, however, when I publish to production, I receive the following error:

**Description**:
 An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details**: 
System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.

**Source Error:** 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

The back end is Visual Basic.

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Navigation.EstablishContext(HttpRequest Request) +492
   Navigation..ctor() +79

[Exception: Error creating Navigation object]
   Navigation..ctor() +269
   UrlRewriteModule.Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e) +262
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +128
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +1513
```

Comment: add VB tag as well please. Share you code for quick response.

Comment: Are you defining custom error handling in your `web.config`?

Comment: yes, however, the vb tags aren't available.  The site is vb compiled, but I cannot figure out where the error is originating from.

Answer (score 0):

Please add your code for a better answer.

You are attempting to access a resource that is not specified in your path, you want to:

- check your url,and identify what is not properly formatted,
- verify your `web.config`
- verify the `permission` on the file you are trying to access on production environment.

99% sure, 404 Not Found = resource not properly accessed.